# Exporting big data to CSV files

Tags: postgresql, coldfusion, coldfusion-9, postgresql-8.4

My current task requires me to export an estimated 100,000 rows of data from a very large database.

I'm fairly new to handing big data and I would love to hear a few best practices and guidelines from people who have **had prior experiences** with these issues that **worked for them in the past** in an effort to make this post **non-subjective**.

A few more details:

- The database is not at all normalized (very ugly)
- I have to deal with at least 100,000 rows in total
- The task is run at midnight with less users
- Currently using ColdFusion 9, PostgreSQL 8.4

Thank you!

This is what my code looks like after applying Craig's solution:

```
<cfset base_path = GetDirectoryFromPath(ExpandPath("*.*")) & "some_parent\some_child\">

<cfif not DirectoryExists(base_path)>
    <cfdirectory directory="#base_path#" action="create" mode="777">
</cfif>

<cfset this_batch_path = DateFormat(Now(), 'mmddyyyy') & TimeFormat(Now(), 'hhmmss') & "\">
<cfdirectory directory="#base_path##this_batch_path#" action="create" mode="777">

<cfset this_filename = "someprefix_" & DateFormat(Now(), 'yyyymmdd') & ".csv">
<cffile action="write" file="#base_path##this_batch_path##this_filename#" output="">

<cfset escaped_copy_path = ListChangeDelims(base_path & this_batch_path & this_filename, "\\", "\")>

<cfquery name="qMyQuery" datasource="some_db" username="some_uname" password="some_pword" result="something">
    COPY some_table TO '#escaped_copy_path#' WITH CSV HEADER;
</cfquery>
```

Now I need to get the count of copied rows.
In the PGSQL 8.4 docs:

> Outputs
>
> On successful completion, a COPY command returns a command tag of the
>   form
>
> COPY count
>
> The count is the number of rows copied.

But I can't seem to get it to work, even with the result tag and the query itself.

Comment: When dealing with large amounts of data and ColdFusion, you have the potential for java heap space problems.  That being the case, look for a way to do this without ColdFusion.  Craig's answer may be the way to go.  It's certainly worth a shot.

Comment: Thank you! I am looking forward to apply his solution to prevent this problem. Thanks!

Comment: Where's your code? What have you tried? What problems did you encounter? It sounds to me like you're inventing a problem before you've actually encountered one?

Comment: Hi @AdamCameron! I just updated my post.

Comment: Can both the database and Coldfusion see the physical path where the CSV file is to be saved?  Perhaps you could write a query for the records required, then write them to the csv file using <cfloop> in Coldfusion. 100,000 records should be an acceptable length to do this.

Comment: To get the number of rows copied, why don't you simply run a select count(*) query?

Comment: Hi, @DanBracuk! Yes, I could do that too, but I was just wondering if there was another way to do it alongside the copy statement instead of making a new one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

100,000 rows isn't big, unless these rows are very very wide with lots of big values.

Just use `psql` and `\copy (SELECT ...) TO '/some/local/file' WITH (FORMAT CSV, HEADER)`

If you want you can estimate the data size:

```
select pg_size_pretty(sum( octet_length(t::text) )) FROM mytable t WHERE ...;
```

For actually big data extract runs, sometimes you may want to use an ETL tool like Talend Studio, Pentaho Kettle or CloverETL.

BTW, it's time to start thinking about upgrading from 8.4 as it's now end-of-life.

Comment: Thank you so much for your insight! Yes, I've been proposing an upgrade for our DB, sadly they always say no.

Comment: @Kevin It gets harder the longer you wait, and eventually you find yourself on something so old nobody even remembers how to fix problems with it anymore, it doesn't run on modern OSes, etc. Planned periodic upgrades are important. I have a customer on 8.2 and most of the issues they have are already fixed/improved in new releases, but they just won't upgrade and spend lots of time and effort working around issues instead.

Comment: Agreed! Not to mention, our main server is still on ColdFusion 9 which already lost core support in 12/31/2014. It makes me sad too.

Comment: I strongly agree with keeping the data processing on the DB, instead of involving CF, which is not intended for heavy DP.